# N+1 queries when submiting validations errors occur

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm having a form where a logged in user can add comments to a post. The form posts to `comments_controller`:

```
# controllers/comments_controller.rb
def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])

    @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:body).merge(:user => current_user))

    if @comment.errors.any?
      render "posts/show"
    else
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    end

    # have also tried this way too
    # @comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment].permit(:body))
    # @comment.user = current_user
    # if @comment.save
    #  redirect_to post_path(@post)
    # else
    #  render "posts/show"
    # end
end

# views/posts/show.html.haml
%h3 This post has #{ pluralize(@post.comments.count, "comment") }
= render @post.comments # views/comments/_comment.html.haml
= render "comments/form" 

# views/comments/_comment.html.haml - list all comments of the post
- if comment && comment.created_at.present?
  .media
    .media-body
      %h4.media-heading
        = comment.user.name
        %small added #{time_ago_in_words comment.created_at} ago
      %p= comment.body
  %hr
```

with the `comment.body` as a required field.

If I try to submit an empty form to a post with no comments, this works fine, the `"posts/show"` view renders with the validation errors, as expected. Now, if I repeat the same steps again in a post which already contains some comments, I'm getting a warning for N+1 Queries running. This is what comes from the `Bullet` gem:

```
N+1 Query detected
  Comment => [:user]
  Add to your finder: :includes => [:user]
N+1 Query method call stack
  /app/views/comments/_comment.html.haml:5:in `_app_views_comments__comment_html_haml__3499194119219243109_33739760'
  /app/views/posts/show.html.haml:23:in `_app_views_posts_show_html_haml__2205508389884571191_36379560'
  /app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:10:in `create'

/app/views/comments/_comment.html.haml:5:in `_app_views_comments__comment_html_haml__3499194119219243109_33739760'
/app/views/posts/show.html.haml:23:in `_app_views_posts_show_html_haml__2205508389884571191_36379560'
/app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:10:in `create'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: what do you have in your `_comment.html.haml` partial ?

Comment: I did an update

Comment: I see, so, you need to load your `comments` and `commens' users` to avoid that error. Try with `Post.includes(comments: :user).find(params[:post_id])`

Comment: Yes, that's it! I was struggling and trying to add  `.includes(:user)` or `.includes(comments: :user)` in the line that has this `@post.comments.create`, as Bullet says `/app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:10:in `create'`, but didn't work out.

Comment: Anyway thanks for the help! Do you want to write this as an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to tell rails to load `post`'s `comments` and `comments`' `user` like this:

```
Post.includes(comments: :user).find(params[:post_id])
```